# Filtro passa antes do servlet de login

Tags: java, servlet, filtro

Boa noite pessoal, estou com uma dúvida, que nem sei se preciso postar o código para solucionar.

O filtro está sendo chamado antes do servlet de login, ou seja, com isso o usuário nunca está logado.

Como faço para que o servlet seja chamado antes? Lembrando que não utilizo o web.xml....

Se não tiver outro jeito, alguém pode me auxiliar de como fazer o web.xml corretamente?

Desde já. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua descrição, estou assumindo que você tem um servlet para validar se o usuário/senha são válidos, e um filtro que apenas verifica se o usuário está logado ou não. Essa separação está correta, e você não precisa chamar o servlet antes, apenas permitir o acesso à página de login:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/login";

        boolean loggedIn = nonNull(session) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("user"));
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);

        if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o acesso à página de login é sempre válido.